# Android Screen will hang in middle of pubnub videochat

Tags: android, webrtc, pubnub

I'm using https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-10-13-build-android-webrtc-video-voice-chat-app/ sample code for doing this.

Sometime android screen will hang on successful connection.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Both Sender,Receiver screen will hang on successful connection.

Comment: Please logs and more specific code examples. Thank you!

Comment: PubNub is not involved in the video portion of this. PubNub is only used for getting the two end users connected, after that, it is video/audio streaming platform, not PubNub.